# WSO2 - Micro Integrator is not connecting to the API Manager

Tags: wso2, wso2-micro-integrator

i downloaded the wso2 Micro integrator and api-manager the two component are up and running.
Now i need to Connect the api-manager to micro integrator through service catalog , i found in api-manager but i need some clarity, how the two components are integrating each other . there're any other way to connect the API-manager and micro integrator.
we don`t have micro-integrator dashboard also.

i have a fresh setup of api-manager and micro integrator,i stared the two components in cmd it`s up and running, i used service catalog in apim, Under Micro Integrator (wso2ei-7.1.0)'s `conf/deployment.toml` file,
i enable this section as well as dashboard also. I couldn't find any logs in log folder 
I have this section:

Comment: [[service_catalog]]
apim_host = "https://localhost:9443"
enable = true
username = "admin"
password = "admin"

Comment: Service catalog is available only in 4.x versions. As per your description you trying with wso2ei-7.1.0, which doesn't support this feature

Answer (score 0):

Integration API Manager and Micro integrator via service catelog is easy.
You just need to add the following configurations in MI deployment toml and publish the integrations.

```
[[service_catalog]]
apim_host = "https://localhost:9443"
enable = true
username = "admin"
password = "admin"
```

Once you have created the integration service and deployed it in the Micro Integrator, you only need to start the two servers (API-M server and the Micro Integrator server). The client in the Micro Integrator publishes the integration services to the API-M layer during server startup.

More information can be found in this [doc page](https://apim.docs.wso2.com/en/latest/integrate/develop/working-with-service-catalog/).